# How to see if there are time conflicts in schedule?

Tags: c++

I have written this program that prints out your schedule in neat way, 
however, my problem is that I have to put a function that detect if there were any conflict time or not, so the program goes like:

```
how many courses you have? 

name of the first course? 
ho many days? 
enter the days?

at what time does your course start?
at what time does your course end?
```

Then it prints out a formatted schedule and shows it to you in a nice way, so that it is easy to read.

Could you please guide me on how to check if there is a conflicting time schedule? Also, my assignment requirement states that I have to make every function be at most 10 lines long!!!

My also instructor said that it would be easier for you to use a military time to find the conflicting time schedules, but the problem is, I do not know how to implement it!

Can you please help me with this or give hints that I may find helpful.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct course {  
   string name;
   int num_days;
   char *days;
   int start_hr, start_min;
   int end_hr, end_min;
};
void get_info(struct course * courses, int num_cour);
void _free(struct course* courses, int num_cour);
void Help();
void pr(struct course *courses, int num_cour);
void pri(struct course *courses, int num_cour);
void prii(struct course *courses, int num_cour);
void priii(struct course *courses, int num_cour);
void priiii(struct course *courses, int num_cour);
void time(struct course *courses, int num_cour);
void conflict(struct course * courses,int num_cour);
int main(){
   course *courses;
   int num_cour;
    cout << " ****************************************************** \n";
/***** here i get the number of the courses ***/   
    cout << "pls enter number of course:"; cin>> num_cour;
    courses = new course[num_cour];

   get_info(courses, num_cour);
   pr(courses, num_cour);
   pri(courses, num_cour);
   prii(courses, num_cour);
   priii(courses, num_cour);
   priiii(courses, num_cour);

   _free(courses, num_cour);

   cout << " ****************************************************** \n";
   return 0;
 }
/***** in this function i get the names of the courses and the days ******/ 
void get_info(struct course* courses, int num_cour)
{  
   for(int i=0; i< num_cour; i++)
   {  
      cout << "name:"; 
      cin>> courses[i].name;
      cout << "How many days" << endl;
      cin>> courses[i].num_days;
      courses[i].days=new char[courses[i].num_days];
      for(int x=0; x < courses[i].num_days ; x++){
         Help(); 
         cout << "Enter the day" << endl;
         cin >> courses[i].days[x];
      }
   }
  time(courses, num_cour); // this is a call for another function that asks the user to enter the time of the courses when it starts and ends. 
}
/******* this function prints out the courses on Mondays only ****/
void pr(struct course *courses, int num_cour){
   cout << "** On Monday **\n";
   for(int i=0; i<num_cour; i++){

      for(int x=0; x<5;x++){
         if(courses[i].days[x]=='m'){
            cout << courses[i].name<<": " << courses[i].start_hr << ":"<<courses[i].start_min << "-" << courses[i].end_hr<< ":" <<courses[i].end_min<< endl;
}

      }
   }
}


/******* this function prints out the courses on tusdays only ****/
void pri(struct course *courses, int num_cour){
   cout << "** On Tusday **\n";
   for(int i=0; i<num_cour; i++){

      for(int x=0; x<5;x++){
         if(courses[i].days[x]=='t'){
            cout << courses[i].name<<": " << courses[i].start_hr<<":"<<courses[i].start_min << "-" << courses[i].end_hr<< ":"<<courses[i].end_min<<endl;
        }

      }

   }
}

/******* this function prints out the courses on Wednesday only ****/
void prii(struct course *courses, int num_cour){

   cout << "** On Wednesday **\n";
   for(int i=0; i<num_cour; i++){

      for(int x=0; x<5;x++){
         if(courses[i].days[x]=='w'){
            cout << courses[i].name<<": " << courses[i].start_hr << ":"<< courses[i].start_min << "-" << courses[i].end_hr<< ":" << courses[i].end_min<< endl;
         }

      }

   }
}
/******* this function prints out the courses on thursdays only ****/
void priii(struct course *courses, int num_cour){
   cout << "** On Thursday **\n";
   for(int i=0; i<num_cour; i++){

      for(int x=0; x<5;x++){
         if(courses[i].days[x]=='r'){
            cout << courses[i].name<<": " << courses[i].start_hr << ":"<< courses[i].start_min << "-" << courses[i].end_hr<< ":" << courses[i].end_min<< endl;
         }

      }

   }
}
/******* this function prints out the courses on fridays only ****/
void priiii(struct course *courses, int num_cour){
   cout << "** On Friday **\n";
   for(int i=0; i<num_cour; i++){

      for(int x=0; x<5;x++){
         if(courses[i].days[x]=='f'){
            cout << courses[i].name<<": " << courses[i].start_hr << ":"<< courses[i].start_min << "-" << courses[i].end_hr<< ":" << courses[i].end_min<< endl;
         }

      }

   }
}

/**** this function to frees out the memory ******/ 
void _free(struct course* courses, int num_cour)
{
   for(int i=0; i<num_cour; i++)
   {
      delete [] courses[i].days;
   }
   delete [] courses;
}

void Help(){

   cout <<"*** NOTE: ENTER (m) for Monday, (t) Tusday, (w) Wednesday, (r) Thursday, (f) Friday ***\n";
}

/******* this function is to get the time where the course starts and ends and it is also been called in an earlier function ****/
void time(struct course *courses, int num_cour){
   for( int i=0; i<num_cour; i++){
      cout << " at what hour is your "<< courses[i].name << " class start: ";
      cin >> courses[i].start_hr;
      cout << " at what minute is your "<< courses[i].name << " class start: ";
      cin >> courses[i].start_min;
      cout << " at what hour is your "<< courses[i].name << " class end: ";
      cin >> courses[i].end_hr;
      cout << " at what minute is your "<< courses[i].name << " class end: ";
      cin >> courses[i].end_min;
   }
}
void conflict(struct course * courses, int num_cour){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to make a separate function for each day of the week. Simply make a string array containing the days of the week. For example:

```
string week[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", ...};
```

To implement a military time structure, try doing

```
class time {
    private:
        int hour;
        int min;
    public:
        void set_hour(int time) hour = time;
        void set_min (int time) min  = time;
        int  get_hour() return hour;
        int  get_min () return min;
}
```